# Does flask-admin import html templates on runtime?

Tags: python, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I am learning the flask framework along with SQLAlchemy .

I am running this test script on a [docker](https://www.docker.com/) container without creating any templates for html pages which I am supposed to do or at least that what the documentation said.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.admin import Admin
from flask.ext.admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

app = Flask(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db_uri = 'mysql://{u}:{p}@{h}/{s}?charset=utf8&use_unicode=1'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = db_uri.format(u='root',
                                                  p='matching',
                                                  h='127.0.0.1',
                                                  s='master_v2')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class UserView(ModelView):

   column_list = ('name', 'email')
   column_searchable_list = ('name', 'email')
   column_filters = ('name', 'email')

class User(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
   email = db.Column(db.String(128))

admin = Admin(app)
admin.add_view(UserView(User, db.session))
me = User(name='me', email='me@mail.com')
you = User(name='you', email='you@gmail.com')
db.create_all()
db.session.add(me)
db.session.add(you)
db.session.commit()
app.run()
```

And once I go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin/user/ it is actually returning an HTML page with a table containing my inserted values in the script.
So How is this page loaded exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go into the source to see what's happening. The ModelView class inherits from BaseModelView, which specifies [specific templates to render for certain views](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/base.py#L126). The default bootstrap2 templates are at [here](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/tree/master/flask_admin/templates/bootstrap2/admin/model). The route that is called via `/admin/user/` is [here](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/base.py#L1697). You'll see that it renders `self.list_template`.